# Hilbert space on a finite set

Tags: abstract-algebra, hilbert-spaces

If X is a finite set, what does the Hilbert space $L^2(X)$ means?  - saw this notion on The Princeton Companion to Mathematics.

Comment: Which bit of the definition of Hilbert space is causing confusion here?

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ contains, say, $n$ elements then $L^2(X)$ reduces to the ordinary Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. EDIT: As commenter points out, here we have implicitly assumed that $X$ is equipped with the counting measure (call it $m$), that is, every subset of $X$ has a measure equal to its cardinality. This way the integral

$$\int_X\lvert f(x) \rvert^2\, dm$$

reduces to the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert f(k)\rvert^2.$$

Comment: I think what's missing is the explicit mention of a measure. So you should say that you take counting measure, for example. Just give *some* positive weight to each point in $X$, otherwise your $L^2$-space won't have dimension $n$.